# How Linux system calls interact with filesystem

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, system-calls

Lately I faced this excercise:

> Given this sequence of system calls in a Linux C language program:

```
fd = open("f123", O_RDWRT | O_CREAT, 0777);
lseek(fd, 0x1000000L, 0);
write(fd, &fd, sizeof(int));
```

> draw the file system data structures and **disk blocks** that are modified by these operations, considering a 4 KByte block size, and index block pointers of 4 bytes.

For the first system call (`open`) I realized how it works and schematized it in this way:
[image: open system call]

Now, skipping the *draw* part (I realize it would make difficult to answer), I'd like to understand how `lseek` and `write` works in term of inodes and index blocks (whatever they are).

I tried figuring that `lseek` computes the correct inode (as block size is known), but still no clue on how it actually works.

Comment: `open()` determines the inode — the other functions use that information.  You need an open file descriptor table and an open file description table (that might be what you mean by 'file table', but I'm not sure).  The description (as opposed to descriptor) holds the seek offset (current position in the file).  In general, multiple descriptors can refer to a single description — and those descriptors need not all be in the same process, though in your example code, there's only one process involved.

Comment: It makes sense. So the lseek just changes the current offset in the description table and then searches for the correct block (if any)?

Comment: `lseek()` doesn't search for the correct block; it doesn't need to.  It's the next I/O operation — as opposed to movement operation — that needs to track blocks.  You can seek way beyond the current end of file, for example.  What happens next depends on whether you read (EOF) or write (new material is written, and any skipped blocks are treated as all bytes zero; the tail of the last block containing the current EOF and the start of the current block may need to be forcibly zeroed).  You can't use negative offsets from the start, but otherwise, `lseek()` succeeds (subject to type limits).

Answer (score 2):

In Linux, these system calls interact with Virtual File System(VFS). VFS builds an abstraction over real filesystems, it defines some useful data structures to organize filesystem.

- **inodes** represents real file on the disk. Through inodes structure can access not only the inode block, but also data blocks on disk.
- **directory entry** represents part of a path. A d_entry doesn't always refer to a real file on the disk. If it refers to a directory on disk, there will be a pointer to the inode struct of the directory file.
- **file** represents files open by processes. There's also a pointer to its d_entry in the struct.

Here are snippets from `file` struct:

```
struct file {
    // ... other attributes
    struct path     f_path;
    #define f_dentry    f_path.dentry
    #define f_vfsmnt    f_path.mnt
    const struct file_operations    *f_op;
};
struct file_operations {
    // ... other operations
    struct module *owner;
    loff_t (*llseek) (struct file *, loff_t, int);
    ssize_t (*read) (struct file *, char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
    ssize_t (*write) (struct file *, const char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
}
```

These objects all has an operation list field. VFS defines these operations and underlaying filesystems implement these operations or use general implementations provided by VFS.

Syscall `open()` creates the file object, other syscalls like `lseek()` simply get `file` object (through Fd) and call the corresponding function in the operation list, like `write()` will call `f->f_op->write(f, ...)`, then filesystem may follow the `file -> d_entry -> inode` path to access file on disk.